# Counting the number of times a word appears in a column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, count, substring

I have a database with 20000 records in it. I want my code to count what records share the first word in their 'title' value. 
This is my code so far and it's returning 1000 records (which I don't think is possible for 1000 words to be shared as the first word of records, with each count being around 20)

what do I need to do to make it count just how many times the first word is shared as the first word? (as in 
record 1: title: 'Bob Joe goes to blah'
record 2: title: 'Bob strikes back'
record 3: title: 'Joe and Bob go home'

It will come back as 'Bob' has 2 counts, not 3 as Joe is the first word in record 3

```
SELECT SUBSTR(TITLE, 1, INSTR(TITLE, ' ') -1) WORD
     , COUNT(SUBSTR(TITLE, 1, INSTR(TITLE, ' ') -1)) NUM 
  FROM FILM 
 GROUP BY SUBSTR(TITLE, 1, INSTR(TITLE, ' ') -1);
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? It seems like it would work to me.

Comment: Could your title have leading spaces and mixed case? Perhaps you should use `LTRIM()` and `UPPER()` on the column. Perhaps you could use `REGEXP_SUBSTR(TITLE, '^[^ ]+')`.

Comment: You don't need anything in the `COUNT()` function here, but that's not your real problem.  You need to look at some of your data, and figure out what it's not grouping that you think it should be.  For example, capitalization (or lack thereof).  Or things like punctuation being included in the word.  I'd imagine your dataset may have a bias for a certain first word `"The"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm) is a bit cleaner.  If I understand your requirement, this should do it:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(TITLE, '\w+') first_word, COUNT(*) 
  FROM film
 GROUP BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(TITLE, '\w+');
```

Comment: Which should also help with some odd corner cases of different (non-space) whitespace, some punctuation, etc.

Comment: Thank you, that works really well and is super clean

Comment: YW. I always get lost in all the INSTR/SUBSTR parameters when I read code that uses them.